# Dependency injection and multiple instances

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring

I am using spring framework for dependency injection, but I simply cannot find out, if I am using it right. Imagine this case - it is not real, but just to explain my problem. I have a spring boot application which connects with websocket to some endpoints. I have a class which has all available methods for this client, stores all needed data for client etc., let's say `Client`. Then I have a static list which holds all connected clients `List<Client>`. I need that the `Client` class is Spring managed bean, as I need to use `@Service` and all other spring features (`@Value`, `@Async`) etc.

The problem is, spring beans are singletons right? How can I instantiate then object from a class which should be spring managed but on the other hand there should be multiple instances of this class?? I cannot use `new` right?`

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessarily true that spring-created objects are singletons; this is merely the default. Spring supports a variety of different options for determining when a new object is created versus an old one being recycled. You should look at the documentation for the "scope" attribute and determine what is most appropriate for your application.

Alternatively, you can create the object yourself using new and then request Spring to configure it for you using the technique described at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable